Does jjwt uses SecureRandom causes blocking call?
Found blocking call
I found Blocking call by BlockHound in my spring webflux app.
I know that jjwt uses SecureRandom to make jwt id(jti) in default.
Here is my stack traces.
reactor.blockhound.BlockingOperationError: Blocking call! java.io.FileInputStream#readBytes at 
java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(FileInputStream.java) ~[na:na] Suppressed: 
reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: Error has been observed at the following
 site(s): checkpoint ⇢ Handler 
tokenserver.infrastructure.adapter.driving.web.auth.AuthController#issueAccessToken(IssueToken
Request) [DispatcherHandler] checkpoint ⇢ HTTP POST "/auth/token/access" 
[ExceptionHandlingWebHandler] Original Stack Trace: at 
java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(FileInputStream.java) ~[na:na] at 
java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:276) ~[na:na] at 
java.base/java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:132) ~[na:na] at 
java.base/sun.security.provider.NativePRNG$RandomIO.readFully(NativePRNG.java:425) ~[na:na] at 
java.base/sun.security.provider.NativePRNG$RandomIO.ensureBufferValid(NativePRNG.java:528) ~[na:na] 
at java.base/sun.security.provider.NativePRNG$RandomIO.implNextBytes(NativePRNG.java:547) ~[na:na]
 at java.base/sun.security.provider.NativePRNG.engineNextBytes(NativePRNG.java:221) ~[na:na] at 
java.base/java.security.SecureRandom.nextBytes(SecureRandom.java:758) ~[na:na] at 
io.jsonwebtoken.impl.crypto.SignatureProvider.<clinit>(SignatureProvider.java:47) ~[jjwt-impl-0.11.5.jar!/:0.11.5] at 
io.jsonwebtoken.impl.crypto.DefaultSignerFactory.createSigner(DefaultSignerFactory.java:36) ~[jjwt-impl-0.11.5.jar!/:0.11.5] at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.crypto.DefaultJwtSigner.<init>(DefaultJwtSigner.java:51) ~[jjwt-impl-0.11.5.jar!/:0.11.5] at 
io.jsonwebtoken.impl.crypto.DefaultJwtSigner.<init>(DefaultJwtSigner.java:39) ~[jjwt-impl-0.11.5.jar!/:0.11.5] at 
io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtBuilder.createSigner(DefaultJwtBuilder.java:360) ~[jjwt-impl-0.11.5.jar!/:0.11.5] at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtBuilder.signWith(DefaultJwtBuilder.java:113) 
~[jjwt-impl-0.11.5.jar!/:0.11.5] at 
tokenserver.infrastructure.adapter.driven.jwt.JWTAdapter.issue(JWTAdapter.kt:34) ~[!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT] at 
tokenserver.application.auth.usecase.AuthUseCase.issueToken$lambda$4(AuthUseCase.kt:38) ~[!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT] at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCallable.call(MonoCallable.java:72) ~[reactor-core-3.6.6.jar!/:3.6.6] at 
reactor.core.publisher.FluxSubscribeOnCallable$CallableSubscribeOnSubscription.run(FluxSubscribeOnCallable.java:228) ~[reactor-core-3.6.6.jar!/:3.6.6] at 
reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:68) ~[reactor-core-3.6.6.jar!/:3.6.6] at reactor.core.scheduler.SchedulerTask.call(SchedulerTask.java:28) ~[reactor-core-3.6.6.jar!/:3.6.6] at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na] at 
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) ~[na:na] at 
java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[na:na]
 at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na] at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]


Edited blocking call to non-blocking
I edited code to use NativePRNGNonBlocking SecureRandom.
And then, blocking call was disappeared.
private val secureRandom = SecureRandom.getInstance("NativePRNGNonBlocking")

    override fun issue(memberId: String, accessLevel: Int, type: TokenType): String {
        val (secret, expiryDate) = helper.getSecretAndExpiry(type)
        return Jwts.builder()
            .signWith(Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(secret.toByteArray(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)), Jwts.SIG.HS256)
            .subject(type.name)
            .claim("memberId", memberId)
            .claim("accessLevel", accessLevel)
            .issuedAt(Date())
            .expiration(Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + expiryDate))
            .apply {
                random(secureRandom)
            }
            .compact()
    }

My Problem
Today, I reproduced the legacy code doesn't use NativePRNGNonBlocking SecureRandom.

    override fun issue(memberId: String, accessLevel: Int, type: TokenType): String {
        val (secret, expiryDate) = helper.getSecretAndExpiry(type)
        return Jwts.builder()
            .signWith(Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(secret.toByteArray(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)), Jwts.SIG.HS256)
            .subject(type.name)
            .claim("memberId", memberId)
            .claim("accessLevel", accessLevel)
            .issuedAt(Date())
            .expiration(Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + expiryDate))
            .compact()
    }

But, there isn't blocking call even though it uses Default SecureRandom.
I wonder why there is no blocking call even though my code uses Default SecureRandom.
If SecureRandom doesn't make blocking call, why blocking call found before???
Is it related about entropy pool???
